# Getting multiple records from SQL Server database with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Can someone tell me why this is not working, please? This will show me the first database record only that matches the WHERE statement and I need it to display all of them that match. Everything works except it only shows the first record that matches. Thank you in advance.

```
using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Month = '" + currentMonth + "' AND Day = '" + currentDay +"'", connection))
{
    DataTable membersTable = new DataTable();
    DataSet info = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(membersTable);
    adapter.Fill(info);

    var rows = info.Tables[0].Rows;

    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    { 
        nameEmployee = info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show (nameemployee);
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is getting you the first record only. `info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();`. You are in the `foreach`, use `row.["Name"].ToString()`.

Comment: Well you're looping through the rows, but inside your loop you're always looking at the first row.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked great.

Answer (score 1):

See the following line:

```
nameEmployee = info.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
```

You are within a foreach loop and have the "current" row in the row variable.  That line should read:

```
nameEmployee = row["Name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Well don't I feel ridiculous. Thank you all. I guess that's what I get for staring at this for three hours trying to figure it out. Embarrassed, thank you.

Comment: @sandratinch anytime you find yourself staring at the same problem for more than an hour, switch to something else for 20 minutes. This let's your brain do an internal reset. You'll look at it again with fresh eyes.

Comment: If you believe this answer to be the correct one, please consider marking it as the correct answer.  Thanks.